# Filebrowser with features like different thumbnail size, improved status bar and more

Tags: software-recommendation, filemanager

I use Nautilus and PCManFM but I need more functionality, maybe you know other file manager which have these functionality:

- sort files with grouping by name, type, etc - and possibility to mix all of them
- thumbnails size regulation by mouse like in MS Windows, because its faster than changing size in settings
- thumbnails of PSD files
- in status bar possibility to show image resolution, not only file size, file type, etc
- tree or favourites or both at the same time

I don't looking for typical image browser because I want see all files, not only images. But please if you know one good you can recommend me it.

Maybe you too working with a lot of image files and text files and you found nice solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no single file manager from what I know, which comes with all those features out of box. But let's look at alternatives we have...

First of all, why not add some functionality to nautilus itself?

Check out these links:

http://www.techdrivein.com/2010/09/6-useful-nautilus-extensions-and.html

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/linux-68-useful-extensions-to-improve-nautilus-functionality/

Also, you may not know everything about Nautilus afterall:

http://www.howtogeek.com/117494/7-ubuntu-file-manager-features-you-may-not-have-noticed/

Nautilus is actually one of the best File Managers available, but there are many alternatives available to you:

Here's a quick list you can read:

http://www.tuxarena.com/2011/06/20-file-managers-for-ubuntu/

Also, look at this question once.

https://superuser.com/questions/56246/ubuntu-is-there-a-better-file-manager-than-nautilus

A quick glance at it suggests two very good file managers to us, which are for other desktop environments by default but are actually pretty good - like dolphin and thunar.

You can also check out this new Marlin file manager, but it's heavily based on nautilus.

http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-marlin-file-manager-on-ubuntu-and-linuxmint-nautilus-alternative/

Comment: Some of the Older links prior to Last two Ubuntu releases are not valid for Current Nautilus Version, it has gone some major changes since then .

Comment: For nautilus extra actions follow [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/nautilus-actions-extra-pack-of-useful.html)

Comment: @tijybba: +1 for the valuable addition! :)